# How to load final class using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to load a final class using the follwoing code

```
final ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
final String classNameToBeLoaded = "demo";
final Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
    // create a new instance
final Constructor cons = demo.class.getConstructor();......(1)
final Object whatInstance = cons.newInstance();
```

it's returning me no such method exception...at 1.What the problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Constructor cons = demo.class.getConstructor();
```

If this fails, this means one of two things:

either there's no default constructor or it's not public ([`class.getConstructor(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) only returns public constructors and if there was a public default constructor, you wouldn't be doing this in the first place).

You can solve the second problem by using [`getDeclaredConstructor(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) instead of `getConstructor()`, it finds constructors with all visibilities:

```
final Constructor<Demo> cons = demo.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
Demo demo = cons.newInstance();
```

The first problem is tougher, obviously :-)

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Without seeing the actual definition of the class in question, we can only guess that the class may have no public default (parameterless) constructor.</strike>

Actually, the problem seems to be that you are trying to get the constructor of the class `Class` instead of the actual class:

```
final Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
    // create a new instance
final Constructor cons = demo.class.getConstructor();......(1)
```

The method call in last line should be `myClass.getConstructor()` instead: `myClass` refers to an object of type `Class`, which is the class token for your `demo` class. So in turn, `myClass.class` refers to the class token of `myClass`, which is the class `Class` itself. Which indeed has no public constructors, as it is not meant to be instantiated just like that.

Btw a class or a variable being `final` has nothing to do with reflection, or class loading issues. You can always load a class, provided it is found on the classpath, is public, and has a public constructor (if the constructor has parameters though, it is a bit more complicated than your code above).

Comment: `myClass.getConstructor()` won't help if the constructor isn't public. It must be `myClass.getDeclaredConstructor()`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Object instance = Class.forName("com.foo.Demo").newInstance();
} catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help if the constructor is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if demo class has a default constructor or a public no-argument constructor.
If you have a private constructor and try to use it to instantiate, you get

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class ... can not access a member of class demo with modifiers "private"`

You just need to use the proper constructor.

Assuming your class has a public constructor that receives and int parameter:

```
public final class Demo {
    private final int i;

    public Demo(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void doSmth() {
        System.out.print("Your number is: " + i);
    }
}
```

Here the *Main* class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        final String classNameToBeLoaded = "Demo";
        final Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);
        // create a new instance
        final Constructor cons = Demo.class.getConstructor(int.class);
        int i = 10;
        final Object whatInstance = cons.newInstance(i);
        // prints: Your number is: 10
        ((Demo) whatInstance).doSmth();
    }
}
```